# "FormatException was unhandled" and program doesn't calculate a result

Tags: c#

I'm currently learning C#, and I got a bit stuck on a assignment. I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and my assignment is as follows:

> Write a program that creates a ProfessorRating class consisting of professor ID and three ratings. The three ratings are used to evaluate easiness, helpfulness, and clarity. In a separate implementation class, allow the user to enter the values. Call the constructor to create an instance of the ProfessorRating class. Include appropriate properties. Do not allow the ID to be changed after an object has been constructed. Provide a method in the ProfessorRating class to compute and return the overall rating average. Print all ratings and the average rating formatted with no digits to the right of the decimal from the implementation class. Use a single class method to enter all data.

So far, I've went through most of the assignment, however I end up running into two bugs that I can't figure out by myself.

The code is in two files, this is the first one:

```
//ProfessorApplication.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lesson4_v4
{
class ProfessorApplication
{
    static void Main( )
    {
        ProfessorRating professorObject = new ProfessorRating();

        int pID;
        int cR;
        int hR;
        int eR;

        DisplayInstructions(); //Show instructions

        pID = DataEntry("Professor ID of the professor you'd like to rate");

        cR = DataEntry("clarity rating of the professor");

        hR = DataEntry("helpfulness rating of the professor");

        eR = DataEntry("easiness rating of the professor");

        professorObject.GradeAverage();

        Console.Clear();

        Console.Write(professorObject);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void DisplayInstructions()
    {
        Console.Beep();
        Console.WriteLine("Hello! This program will allow you to calculate a Professor's rating based on three categories!");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("You will be asked for the the professor ID and a grade of 1-10.");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("Please refer to the scale below.");
        Console.WriteLine(" ");
        Console.WriteLine("  0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7   8    9    10 ");
        Console.WriteLine("Worst                                             Best");
        Console.Read();
    }

    static int DataEntry(string rating1)
    {
        string inputValue;
        int Rating;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the {0}: ",rating1);
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        Rating = int.Parse(inputValue); //System.FormatException was unhandled according to VS2010
    }
}
}
```

Here's the code from the second file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Lesson4_v4
{
    class ProfessorRating
    {
    private int professorID; // Professor ID
    int helpRating; // Helpfulness Rating
    int cleaRating; // Clarity Rating
    int easyRating; // Easiness Rating

    public ProfessorRating() //default constructor           
    {

    }

    public ProfessorRating(int pID) //1 parameter constructor
    {
        professorID = pID;
    }

    public ProfessorRating(int pID, int hR, int cR, int eR) //all parameter constructor
    {
        professorID = pID;
        helpRating = hR;
        cleaRating = cR;
        easyRating = eR;
    }

    public int GradeAverage() //is supposed to calculate the average, but shows as "0"
    {
        return (helpRating + cleaRating + easyRating) / 3;
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "The average is " + GradeAverage();
    }
}
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change datatype from integer to double.

ie, Change following

```
    int pID;
    int cR;
    int hR;
    int eR;
```

To

```
    double pID;
    double cR;
    double hR;
    double eR;
```

Integer division causes 0, when numerator is less than denominator.

For the FormatException, You have to make sure that you are entering correct digits. If you are entering characters, you are likely to get this exception.

You can use [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) that returns false in case of parsing error (instead of FormatException). This way you can handle wrong input better.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I changed the integers to double, but VS is now showing an error at 'static int DataEntry(string rating1)' It says " 'Lesson4_v4.ProfessorApplication.DataEntry(string)': not all code paths return a value" I tried changing the other integers to doubles, but the problem still persisted.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is Regarding to your comment which is you add in @Tilak sir's Answer.

```
static int DataEntry(string rating1)
{
    string inputValue;
    int Rating;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the {0}: ",rating1);
    inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
    Rating = int.Parse(inputValue); //System.FormatException was unhandled according to VS2010
}
```

so add following line for removing "not all code paths return a value " Error.

```
    static int DataEntry(string rating1)
    {
        string inputValue;
        int Rating;
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the {0}: ",rating1);
        inputValue = Console.ReadLine();
        Rating = int.Parse(inputValue); //System.FormatException was unhandled according to VS2010
Return Rating;
    }
```

your are getting "not all code paths return a value " Error because DataEntry is int Method and it should be return some value...

Hope it will useful for you....

Comment: Well, it did fix the build issue, but then still gives me the FormatException error, and I can't enter anything before it happens.

Answer (score 0):

you will always return Zero because you are calling the wrong constructor function please do as the previous two suggested and then change

```
static void Main( )
{
    ProfessorRating professorObject = new ProfessorRating();

    int pID;
    int cR;
    int hR;
    int eR;
```

Move `ProfessorRating professorObject = new ProfessorRating();` down under the variables and state the constructor method by changing professorObject to call the appropriate method.

```
pID = DataEntry("Enter the ID of the Professor you would like to rate");
        cR = DataEntry("Please rate the clearity of the information provided");
        hR = DataEntry("Please rate your instructor on their helpfulness");
        eR = DataEntry("Please rate your material on its easiness");

        ProfessorRating professorObject = new ProfessorRating(pID, cR, hR, eR);
        professorObject.GradeAverage();
```